# Executing a script within a script but continuing on error(s) and saving them to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, try-except, execfile

If I was to have the following bit of code:

```
try: 
    execfile("script.py")
except ## unsure what exception goes here...
    continue:
try: 
    execfile("other.py")
except ## unsure what exception goes here...
    continue:
```

How do I catch all errors from script.py save it to file and then continue onto the next called script

Anyone have any ideas or clues?

Comment: replace "continue" with some code that writes an error on a file?

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou I was unsure how to do that part, the catching of the error is where I was stuck. Really simple things can sometimes be too obvious as was the case here.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. I think the answer rogaos gave, got you unstuck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
errors = open('errors.txt', 'w')
try: 
    execfile("script.py")
except Exception as e:
    errors.write(e)
try: 
    execfile("other.py")
except Exception as e:
     errors.write(e)
errors.close()
```

Comment: Hmm, that's easier than I expected. 

Thank you ever so much, upvote and accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import traceback # This module provides a standard interface to extract, 
                 # format and print stack traces of Python programs.

try: 
    execfile("script.py")
except:
    traceback.print_exc(file=open('script.traceback.txt', 'w')) # Writing exception with traceback to file script.traceback.txt

# Here is the code that will work regardless of the success of running a script.py
```

Comment: Interesting method of doing it, I'll use that aswell as rogoas's version.